# Origin of doolally [tap]

Tags: etymology

I've used ***doolally*** since I was a child, but I'd rarely heard the ***tap*** version until a few years ago in the company of several Welsh people (who *all* agreed the two-word version was their "standard").

They said it referred to insanity caused by contaminated tap water in Deolali (lead?, cadmium?).

But I've now discovered [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doolally) says...

> "Doolally", originally "doolally tap", meaning to 'lose one′s mind', derived from the boredom felt at the Deolali British Army transit camp. 'Tap' may be derived from the Sanskrit word 'tapa' meaning 'heat' or 'fever'. It is also just conceivable that it derives from the Welsh word 'twp', meaning 'stultified', 'unable to reason sensibly'.

Can anyone either corroborate or refute any of these suggested etymologies?

Comment: It is all new to me. I had never considered the origin of the term though I have used it many times myself. I have never heard the 'tap' version.

Comment: Interesting, that. I’ve heard both (though neither more than perhaps a dozen times, so I have no idea which I’ve heard more), and also just ‘tap’ on its own in the same sense. I never gave the etymology a second thought—I always just assumed that _doolally_ is merely phonaesthetic and _tap_ refers to tapping your temple or forehead to indicate that someone is bonkers!

Comment: Also, one must presume that if _tap_ is indeed from Welsh _twp_ (which seems rather implausible to begin with—the vowel change alone would be highly irregular), then _doolally_ almost has to have a different origin, too. No one in their right mind would add a Welsh word to the name of an Indian city to make an English term: the two source languages are just too far apart, but socially and geographically.

Comment: (Damn typos. That was supposed to say “both socially and geographically” in my previous comment.)

Comment: @Janus: Reading your comments yesterday was pretty much sufficient to convince me *tap* here didn't come from Welsh. But the absolute clincher was to discover the relevant definition in OED, with a citation from long before the *doolally tap* collocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Doolally*** comes from British army slang, originating when Deolali was a British army transit camp in India.

***Doolally tap*** meant being mad, crazy or literally, suffering from camp fever. ***Tap*** in English is malarial fever, from the Hindi for fever.

*The Madness at Deolali* (Journal of the Royal Army Medical Corps) by Major NA Martin begins:

> The slang word ‘doolally’ or ‘doolali’ is used
>   to describe someone who is ‘out of one’s
>   mind’ or ‘crazy’. It is a derivation of
>   ‘doolali-tap’ and originates from the latter
>   part of the nineteenth century.The first part
>   of this phrase is derived from the name of a
>   small military town in the Indian state of
>   Maharashtra called Deolali. The second
>   part is a Hindustani word for fever, often
>   ascribed to malaria, although in Sanskrit,
>   ‘tapa’ means simply heat or torment. Taken
>   literally, it is best translated as ‘camp fever’.
>   By the time of the Second World War, the
>   term had been shortened to ‘doolally’.

A mixture of boredom, syphilis, venereal diseases, heat, mosquitoes, fever, malaria, sand fleas contributed to misery at the camp.

He concludes:

> Frank Richards wrote, *`The well known saying among soldiers when speaking of a man                    who does queer things, "Oh, he's got the Doolally tap, " originated, I think, in the peculiar way men behaved owing to the boredom of that camp*'(2). While this may have been true at times, the reason that Deolali became synonymous with mental illness has more to do with the limitations imposed on troop movements by the seasons, the debilitating effect of the summer climate, alcoholism, venereal diseases, malaria, and the difficulties of treating mental illness in the colonies.

The OED's first recorded use is in 1925 but I found some 1916 examples.

A booklet titled *[The Way They Have in the Army](https://archive.org/details/waytheyhaveinarm00otooiala)* (1916) by Thomas O'Toole has a chapter on on Tommy's Private Language:

> Doolally Tap. When a soldier becomes 
>   mentally unbalanced, he is said to have 
>   received the " Doolally Tap." " Doolally " 
>   is a corruption of the name of an Indian 
>   town, Deolali.

The booklet and quoted in Australian newspapers: the [*Brunswick and Coburg Leader*](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/87675352?searchTerm=doolally&searchLimits=dateTo=1917-12-31%7C%7C%7Csortby=dateDesc) of Friday 12 May 1916 and [*The Australasian*](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/142992293/15082252?searchTerm=doolally#pstart15082252) of the next day.

Comment: I'm going to plump for this answer, mainly because you've explicitly mentioned that ***tap** in English is malarial fever*. Although you haven't posted an online dictionary link confirming that, it was enough to nudge me to check OED myself. And that definition is indeed listed, with first citation 1882 - over 40 years before their first citation for *doolally tap*. So I'm now fully convinced those Welsh folk were simply wrong.

Comment: I've sent the antedatings to the OED.

Comment: They will be glad of it, I'm sure. But even if it checks out, we're still talking about *tap = malarial fever* having been recorded decades earlier than *Doolally tap*.

Comment: Yes. There's a whole raft of [place] [word-for-fever] names, like Malta dog, Hong Kong dog, Ceylon sore mouth, Aztec two-step, Greek gallop, Rome runs, Tokyo trots, from soldiers and sailors getting sick in hot places (http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50805/9001). This sounds like originally just another variant, that's then changed meanings and lost the tap.

Answer (score 3):

According to the  Etymonline Dictionary the original expression actually was *doolally tap*:

> - *Doolally* comes from the name of Deolai, a location near Bombay where the BritishnArmy had a camp.
> - *Tap* seems to derive from a local word meaning *fever*. The 'fever' in question refers to the impatience of soldiers to go back home after their enlistments had expired.

[Doolally](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Doolally&searchmode=none) (adj.)

"insane, eccentric," British slang, by 1917 in the armed services and in full doolally tap (with Urdu word for "fever"), *from Deolali, near Bombay, India, which was a military camp (established 1861) with a large barracks and a chief staging point for British troops on their way to or from India;* **the reference is to men whose enlistments had expired who waited there impatiently for transport home.**

Answer (score 1):

It's English army slang

> **Doolally Tap** -when a soldier becomes mentally unbalanced he is said to
>   have received the “Doolally Tap.” “Doolally” is a corruption of the
>   name of an Indian town, Deolali. -**Rhymes of the rookies** . Christian, W. E.

& a fiction reference from Champion road [1950]that uses 'doolally' as a synonym for crazy:

> "He's not behaving more than twenty-four!" I snapped before there was
>   time to check myself, and then, seeing the expression on her face:
>   "She's nought a pound, Janet, not a patch on you, not fit to lick your
>   boots. Unless **he's doolally** he'll come back to you all right.
>   Chaps only go after women like that for one thing." -